# Firebase Storage access control - single user as interface

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

Assuming that in my system there is already a method of authentication and have thousand users.

If I have a single user on the firebase with a single UID, this can it serve as an "interface" and distribute tokens for all my users to just control access to Firebase Storage and allow sending the images for example?

Or, if A and B request tokens for the same Firebase UID in the same time, B invalidates the token of A?

This question is intended to find out if it is possible to have a "single user as interface" to not import many users and manage them both on my system as well as on the firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical limitation in Firebase Authentication that limits a single user to signing in only from a single device.

What you're proposal is essentially to create a single user account, and give the email and password for that account to all of your users. While this may be technically possible, I'd recommend against it.

The chances of someone's credentials leaking increase as you have more users. When each user has their own unique account, the impact of a single leak is limited to that one account. But if all users share the same credentials, one user leaking those credentials impacts all of your users.

So while it may be technically possible, I'd consider it an anti-pattern. Even if it doesn't set of any abuse-protection alarm bells today, there is no guarantee that this won't change in the future.